# What is an Idiomatic way to check if a container is running and invoke a function at certain interval?

Tags: docker, go

I am using Docker Go SDK to launch a container. Here is the code I am using:

```golang
    resp, err := cli.ContainerCreate(ctx, &container.Config{
        Image: "logs2gist",
        Cmd:   nil,
    }, nil, nil, nil, "")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := cli.ContainerStart(ctx, resp.ID, types.ContainerStartOptions{}); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

I have also found in documentation that we can wait for a container to finish:

```golang
    statusCh, errCh := cli.ContainerWait(ctx, resp.ID, container.WaitConditionNotRunning)

    select {
    case err := <-errCh:
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    case <-statusCh:
    }

    return resp.ID
```

I wonder if there is an idiomatic way to run a function while we wait for a container to finish. In my case, I want to fetch logs from the container at each X minutes, and send it to an external API.

Non idiomatic way to deal with it is to:

1. Run a infinite for loop.
2. Check if container is still running; if not break the loop
3. If it is running, take the logs, and post it to an API.
4. Sleep for X number of minutes.

Comment: *"Non idiomatic way to deal with it is to: ..."* -- How did you come to the conclusion that that's unidiomatic? What specifically in those 4 steps makes the solution unidiomatic? Using infinite loops with a select statement is as idiomatic as anything I can really think of.

Comment: What I don't like about that approach is, it works separately from the flow. I also don't like infinite loop operations. I was wondering if we can hack `cli.ContainerWait` in some why.

Comment: You can wrap the state in a struct type, have it implement a predicate `next() bool` which you can then use in the `for` loop's clause. That could still be considered idiomatic although perhaps unnecessary.

Comment: Keep in mind that what *you* don't like is not necessarily unidiomatic. Plenty of devs coming from languages where exceptions were the default do not like Go's `if err != nil { ... }` error handling. But, in fact, as you probably already know, there's hardly anything more idiomatic than that.

Comment: Any time you need to poll for something, there is an "infinite loop" involved, you just may not be writing it directly in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Using an infinite `for` loop with a `select` statement is perfectly idiomatic.

```golang
tick := time.NewTicker(10 * time.Minute)
defer tick.Stop()

statusCh, errCh := cli.ContainerWait(ctx, resp.ID, container.WaitConditionNotRunning)
for {
    select {
    case err := <-errCh:
        // handle error & exit
        return
    case <-statusCh: // not running?
        // get the last logs & exit...
        return
    case <-tick.C:
        // get the latest logs ...
    }
}
```

---

If you don't like that approach however, you may want to consider something similar to how `*sql.Rows` provides access to the underlying db data.

```golang
type waiter struct {
    tick   *time.Ticker
    chWait <-chan container.ContainerWaitOKBody
    chErr  <-chan error
    wait   bool
    err    error
}

func (w *waiter) next() bool {
    if w.wait && w.err == nil {
        select {
        case err := <-w.chErr:
            w.err = err
            return true
        case <-w.chWait:
            w.wait = false
            return true
        case <-w.tick.C:
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func (w *waiter) close() {
    w.tick.Stop()
    // ... other cleanup if necessary ...
}
```

The constructor

```golang
func newWaiter(ctx context.Context, containerID string, condition container.WaitCondition, tickDur time.Duration) *waiter {
    tick := time.NewTicker(tickDur)
    chWait, chErr := cli.ContainerWait(ctx, containerID, condition)
    return &waiter{
        tick:   tick,
        chWait: chWait,
        chErr:  chErr,
    }
}
```

And you'd use it like so:

```golang
w := newWaiter(ctx, resp.ID, container.WaitConditionNotRunning, 10*time.Minute)
defer w.close()

for w.next() {
    // grab logs
}
if w.err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```